# How set null on field using symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.7

I'm using Symfony 2.7.39 and FOSRestBundle to build a simple REST api.
In this case I have this entity:

```
    class DocumentacionMaquina extends Documentacion
    {
      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Archivo", cascade={"all"})
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="declaracion_conformidad_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
       *
       * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
       */
      private $declaracion_conformidad;
        // ...
    }
```

ArchivoType:

```
    class ArchivoType extends AbstractType
    {
      /**
       * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
       * @param array $options
       */
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
        $builder->add('nombre');
      }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => 'PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Archivo',
          'csrf_protection' => false,
          'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
      }
    }
```

DocumentacionMaquinaType:

```
    class DocumentacionMaquinaType extends DocumentacionType
    {
      /**
       * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
       * @param array $options
       */
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
```

```
    $builder
      ->add('maquina', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Maquina' 
      ))
      ->add('declaracion_conformidad', new ArchivoType(),
        array('required'=>false)
      )
    ;
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class' => 'PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\DocumentacionMaquina',
      'csrf_protection' => false,
      'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
    }
}
```

When I create a new DocumentacionMaquina entity launching a POST it works as expected:

```
    {
    "pdca_restbundle_documentacion":
      {
        "maquina": 752,
        "declaracion_conformidad": {
        "nombre": "fichero10"
      }
    }
```

But I would like to send a null (edit entity and create new entities with optional Archivo):

```
    {
    "pdca_restbundle_documentacion":
      {
        "maquina": 752,
        "declaracion_conformidad": null
    }
```

This is the validation error when I send a null value:

> This value is not valid.

In my controller:

```
    $entity = new DocumentacionMaquina();
    $form = $this->createForm(new DocumentacionMaquinaType(), $entity, array('method' => $request->getMethod()));

    $form->submit($request->get($form->getName()), false);

    if !($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->view(array('form' => $form), Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

---

**EDIT #1**
I created a simple entities with no inheritance for test but with equal result.

Entity Prueba:

```
namespace PDCA\RestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Prueba
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details"})
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Hijo", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="marcado_ce_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details"})
     */
    private $marcado_ce;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=false, length=255, nullable=false)
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details"})
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $nombre;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set marcado_ce
     *
     * @param \DateTime $marcado_ce
     * @return Prueba
     */
    public function setMarcadoCe(Hijo $marcado_ce = null)
    {
        $this->marcado_ce = $marcado_ce;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get marcado_ce
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getMarcadoCe()
    {
        return $this->marcado_ce;
    }
    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Prueba
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

Entity Hijo

```
namespace PDCA\RestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 */
class Hijo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details", "backend_creacion"})
     */
    private $id;
        /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=false, length=255, nullable=false)
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details"})
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $nombre;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Artchivo
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

PruebaType and HijoType:

```
namespace PDCA\RestBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Prueba;
class PruebaType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('marcado_ce', new HijoType(), array('required'=>false))
        ;
    }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        /** @var OptionResolver $resolver */
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Prueba',
                'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pdca_restbundle_prueba';
    }
}
```

Type Hijo

```
namespace PDCA\RestBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class HijoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('nombre')
        ;
    }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        /** @var OptionResolver $resolver */
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'PDCA\RestBundle\Entity\Hijo',
                'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$entity = new Prueba();
$form = $this->createForm(new PruebaType(), $entity, array('method' => $request->getMethod()));

$form->submit($request->get($form->getName()), false);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    //Persist $entity
}
return $this->view(array('form' => $form), Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
```

When I do a POST with subentity, entities Prueba and Hija are persisted sucesfully:

```
{
    "pdca_restbundle_prueba": {
         "nombre": "nombre prueba",
          "marcado_ce": 
              {
                "nombre": "fichero4"
              }
     }
}
```

But when I use "marcado_ce": null:

```
{
    "pdca_restbundle_prueba": {
         "nombre": "nombre prueba2",
          "marcado_ce": null
     }
}
```

This fail with this message:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": {
        "errors": [
            "Este valor no es valido."
        ],
        "children": {
            "nombre": {},
            "marcado_ce": {
                "children": {
                    "nombre": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging this problem, here is where code launch an exception resulting in validation failed:
File Form.php, line 570:

```
  if ($this->config->getCompound()) {
      if (null === $submittedData) {
          $submittedData = array();
      }

      if (!is_array($submittedData)) {
          **throw new TransformationFailedException('Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission.');**
      }
```

I uploaded a image with stack trace here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzPDc.png

I edited Form.php code replacing Exception code with this (line 750). But this isn't a solution. I will try to understand what is the root cause, maybe I miss something with symfony-forms.

```
if (!is_array($submittedData)) {
  $submittedData = array();
}
```

Comment: I think this problem relates to `'cascade_validation' => true` in your form. It looks like the validation on your Archivo entity is triggered, even when it's empty. Can you just for testing purposes remove the option and see if it works?

Comment: Hi dbrumann, thanks for your time reading me. I deleted 'cascade_validation' => true but with no luck. I created a simple entities called Prueba and Hijo but with equal results. I tried to debug this problem  but at this moment I don't find a good solution.